# The Coursera autograder gives me Unknown Signal 11

Tags: c++, signals, greedy

I'm in a class in Algorithms and now we are taking Greedy Algorithms.
Two of my solutions output "Uknown Signal 11" on some of the test cases.

However, I drove my program to the limit with the largest inputs possible.
It works just fine on my PC. However on Coursera's grader, it throws tgghis cryptic message of Unknown Signal 11.

Will this go away if I change to Python for example?

Here's the first code exhibiting the problem:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <utility>
 #include <algorithm>
 using namespace std;

bool sortAlg(pair<double, pair<uint64_t,uint64_t>> item1, pair<double, 
pair<uint64_t,uint64_t>> item2)
{
return (item1.first >= item2.first);
}
int main()
{
uint64_t n, index = 0;
double W, val;
cin >> n >> W;
pair<double, pair<uint64_t,uint64_t>> items[n];
for (int i=0; i <n; i++)
{
    cin >> items[i].second.first >> items[i].second.second;
    items[i].first =  (double)items[i].second.first / (double)items[i].second.second;
}
sort(items,items+n, sortAlg);

while(W > 0 && n > 0)
{
    if (items[index].second.second <= W)
    {

        val += items[index].second.first;
        W -= items[index].second.second;
        index++;
        n--;
    }
    else
    {
        val += items[index].first * W;
        W = 0;
        index++;
        n--;
    }
}
printf("%.4f",val);
return 0;
}
```

I think this has to do with the while loop, but I can't think of anything where the program will make an out of bounds array call using index.

Anyways it is a fractional knapsack implementation.

Here's the second code which also gives unknown signal 11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

bool sortAlg(string num1, string num2)
{
    if (num1[0] > num2[0]) return true;
    else if (num1[0] < num2[0]) return false;
    else
{
    if (num1.size() == 1 && (num1[0] > num2[1])) return true;
    else if (num1.size() == 1 && (num1[0] < num2[1])) return false;
    else if (num2.size() == 1 && (num1[1] > num2[0])) return true;
    else if (num2.size() == 1 && (num1[1] < num2[0])) return false;
    else if (num1 == "1000" || num2 == "1000") return (num1 < num2);
    else
    {
        if (num1.size() == num2.size()) return (num1 > num2);
        else
        {
            return (num1[1] > num2[1]);
        }
    }
}
}

int main()
{
string num;
int n, n2 = 1;
cin >> n;
//int numbers[n];
vector<string> numbers2;
for (int i =0; i <n; i++)
{
    num = to_string(n2);
    cout << num << endl;
    numbers2.push_back(num);
    n2 += 10;
}
sort(numbers2.begin(), numbers2.end(), sortAlg);

for (auto number : numbers2)
{
    cout << number;
}
return 0;
}
```

I suspect the sortAlg function used in sort function, but on my PC it is relatively fast. And the problem statement required some weird sorting.

The problem was given a set of numbers, arrange them to make thebiggest number possible.

If given 9, 98, 2, 23, 21 for example it should give me 99823221.
(9 > 98 > 23 > 2 > 21)
So I sort by the first digit then the next and so on.

Comment: That's likely a seg fault due to mishandling memory. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Comment: How do I fix this? or Is it beyond me?

Comment: Have some code for us to look at? Python may indeed be better as it is harder to crash and easier to debug

Comment: It's more likely to be a problem with an edge case than with input size. These can usually be reproduced with small and systematically chosen test cases.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: Edited as recommended :)

Comment: I have a hunch that your comparison is not a strict weak ordering, leading to undefined behaviour.

Comment: It is not a strict weak order or anything. It is a weird ordering scheme for the problem. But it has a defined behaviour.

Comment: @RaafatAbualazm The relation *must* be a strict weak ordering, otherwise the behaviour of `sort` is undefined.

Comment: But I'm telling it what to do in each and every step.

Comment: @RaafatAbualazm That's not enough. You can read about the requirements on the ordering relation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare).

Comment: Then? This weird sorting is the way to solve this for me.
Why does it work on my PC then?

Answer (score 2):

You have a StackOverflow error.

The necessary stack size depends on the depth of your recursion, the number of parameters of your recursive function and on the number of local variables inside each recursive call.

In Python, you have to set the necessary stack size. The starter files provided in Python 3 would have the sample below:

```
import threading

sys.setrecursionlimit(10 ** 6)  # max depth of recursion
threading.stack_size(2 ** 27)  # new thread will get stack of such size
...
threading.Thread(target=main).start()
```

Note how the `stack_size` is allocated.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an additional information related to Coursera grader.
In the week 6 the same course , if you declare a 2D array for the dynamic programming problem, the  grader gives the Signal 11 error and program fails even if it is working perfectly fine on local machine .

Solution to above problem - replace 2-D array by 2D vector (in case of C++) and submit again. The grader will accept the code solution and no signal 11 error will be thrown.